# How to make a complex function with a specific condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with the following question.

**Problem:**
Let $a<b<c$ be natural numbers with a condition $a+b<c$.
In this case, $0<a< b<a+b<c<a+c$ holds.
Make a complex function $f(z)$ that satisfies all of the conditions below.

(1)$f(z)$ is holomorphic in a domain containing $z=0,b$ but cannot be extended to an entire function.

(2)Power series expansion about the point $z=0$ has a radius of convergence $a+b$.

(3)Power series expansion about the point $z=a$ has a radius of convergence $a+c$.

**My attempt:**
So we need to have some kind of singularity to our function as it cannot be extended to an entire function. I thought I would go with $f(z)=\frac{1}{z-(a+b)}$, but it does not satisfy (3), as the radius of convergence would be $b$ at $z=a$. And I did not come up with any other ideas.

Comment: How about putting another pole at $z=-c$?

Comment: @AnginaSeng So $f(z)= 1/(z+c)(z-a-b)$? I thought the radius of convergence would still be $b$ at $z=a$ because of the pole at $z=a+b$.